# Crosswalk generates a 225 MB APK file

Tags: android, crosswalk

I'm trying to do my first Crosswalk build (with crosswalk-pkg v0.10.5).

It's using just a simple manifest *without any application files*:

```
{
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "name": <omitted>,
  "short_name": <omitted>,
  "display": <omitted>,
  "start_url": "https://<omitted>,
  "theme_color": "#83a441",
  "xwalk_app_version": "0.1",
  "xwalk_package_id": "it.<omitted>,
  "xwalk_permissions": [
    "Geolocation",
    "Vibration"
  ],
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "android-icon-36x36.png",
      "sizes": "36x36",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": "0.75"
    },
    {
      "src": "android-icon-48x48.png",
      "sizes": "48x48",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": "1.0"
    },
    {
      "src": "android-icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": "1.5"
    },
    {
      "src": "android-icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": "2.0"
    },
    {
      "src": "android-icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": "3.0"
    },
    {
      "src": "android-icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": "4.0"
    }
  ]
}
```

So the `start_url` references an external website and no application assets are included within the APK itself.

Simply running `crosswalk-pkg --release .` genates (working) **huge** APK files:

- 221 MB for ...armeabi-v7a.apk
- 225 MB for ...x86.apk

AFAIK the APK should be around ~25 MB in size.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.

The problem was that the directory containing `manigest.json` contained large binary files (older APK builds) that were included in the builds.

Cleaning up the directory produced 23 / 27 MB builds.